# Checking For Nullable Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to check if `GroupEmails` is `null` before executing this section of my code. However, whenever I am checking for the `null` value, it returns an error `Cannot resolve symbol GroupEmails` Is there a better solution for this?

**Code**

```
Group = new DB.Group
{
    GroupPhones = groupPhones,

    GroupEmails = new List<DB.GroupEmail>
    {
        new DB.GroupEmail
        {
            Email = groupt.Email
        }
    }
}
```

**Trying to check if null like the following:**

```
Group = new DB.Group
{
    GroupPhones = groupPhones,

    GroupEmails == null ? null : new List<DB.GroupEmail>
    {
        new DB.GroupEmail
        {
            Email = groupt.Email
        }
    }
}
```

**Modified Solution Thanks to @Habib**

```
Group = new DB.Group
{
    GroupPhones = groupPhones,

    GroupEmails = group.Email == null ? null : new List<DB.GroupEmail>
                                               {
                                                  new DB.GroupEmail
                                                  {
                                                    Email = groupt.Email
                                                  }
                                                }
}
```

Comment: Where did you check if `groupt` is null or not?

Comment: If this did work you're saying if it is null, then set it to null.  Which wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no need to check** for null in [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

```
 GroupEmails == null ? null : new List<DB.GroupEmail>
```

`GroupEmails` property is being initialized in the object initializer for `new DB.Group`.

This shouldn't even compile as you can't perform checks like these on properties/fields in object initializer.

If you want to initialize your property `GroupEmail` irrespective of data then you can do:

```
Group = new DB.Group
{
    GroupPhones = groupPhones,
    GroupEmails = new List<DB.GroupEmail>(),
}
```

or if you want to compare `group.Email` to null, then you can do:

```
GroupEmails = group.Email == null ? null : new List<DB.GroupEmail>
                                          {
                                            new DB.GroupEmail
                                            {
                                              Email = groupt.Email
                                            }
                                          }
```

Comment: The issue I am running into is that it generates an error while running if I don't pass in any data for the `GroupEmails`. How could I fix that?

Comment: @CodeChaser If that's the problem then show that code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: @CodeChaser, your first code snippet should work fine as long as you have some valid value in `groupt.Email` , otherwise you can simply initialize the `GroupEmails` like ` GroupEmails = new List<DB.GroupEmail>(),` and leave the `List` initialization.

Comment: @Habib you are right, no need to check for a null value on `GroupEmails`. I ended up changing it to look like the following: `GroupEmails = group.Email == null ? null : new List<DB.GroupEmail>`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the object, so I'm not sure why you would check for `null`...

```
var group = new DB.Group();
group.GroupPhones = groupPhones;
group.GroupEmails = new List<DB.GroupEmail>();
group.GroupEmails.Add(new DB.GroupEmail() { Email = groupt.Email });
```